# `Breeze.Server.ContextProvider.NH not exist

Tags: breeze

Following the documentation described in [this link](http://www.breezejs.com/documentation/start-nuget), I'm trying to install the Breeze with NHibernate support.

But the `Breeze.Server.ContextProvider.NH` does not exist, what should I do? What are the steps to use Breeze with NHibernate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Breeze.ContextProvider.NH source and dll is available on GitHub, but we are still in testing on it, so we haven't created a nuget package for it yet.

Comment: Some example using NHibernate + webapi 2.0?

Comment: It's on our list. Please add this to the Breeze User Voice so that we can get further feedback.

Answer (score 0):

The nuget package is now available, and the [NorthBreeze sample](http://www.breezejs.com/samples/northbreeze) 
is now updated to use Breeze 1.4.8 and WebApi 2

I updated the sample by removing all the existing references, then installing the nuget package [Breeze.WebApi2.NH](http://www.nuget.org/packages/Breeze.WebApi2.NH/)

Except for some `using` statements, and one redundant line of the Web.config, I didn't need to change any code.